# how to install laravel already build website

Tags: php, mysql, linux, laravel, wamp

I've purchased laravel script http://ondemandbay.com/. I'm trying to install already build laravel website on local server(wamp) as well as live shared server (linux). please help to install script.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check any of the  [easily found guides on deployment](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.v85jue84y)?

Comment: It is recommended you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to be introduced to asking good and valuable questions.

Comment: I have checked few tours, but most of about new installation, rather than configure old build.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

> Via Composer Create-Project
>
> You may also install Laravel by issuing the Composer create-project command in your terminal

You need to install composer (https://getcomposer.org/). This is for the **composer** command.

{directory} can be replaced with the folder you want for your Laravel installation (for example /my-laravel-site).

More information can be found at the laravel documentation page: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2

Comment: this command will install fresh laravel or my old build ? because I want to configure my old build not fresh

Comment: this will install a new laravel 4.2 installation.

Do you want your "own old build"?

Comment: yes I want to configure my old build

Comment: Where do you have you old build? Did you save it somewhere?

Comment: it's paid Uber taxi app script http://ondemandbay.com/